# Lazy module can not be found although path seems correct

Tags: angular, angular6, nativescript, nativescript-angular

link: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Annyna&v=4

error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "./TrainingUnit", relative to: app/trainingunit/list/`

Its odd that the module name in the error message is: "./TrainingUnit"

The module **file name** is: trainingunit.module

The module **class name** is: TrainingUnitModule

Both module "names" seem correct.

As I assume there error is in the AppRouterModule:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/trainingunits", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "trainingunits", loadChildren: "./trainingunit/list/trainingunit.module#TrainingUnitModule" }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't included the `TrainingUnit` module in your `@NgModule` list.

Comment: The default generated app for NS + Angular on NS playground does not either include the HomeModule: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Annyna&v=5, WHERE exactly do you think have I missed the including of the module then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TrainingUnitComponent you are trying to import `TrainingUnit` from `./TrainingUnit` but the file name should should be `./trainingunit`. Update to import the class from the correct file and you should be good to go.

#### trainingunit.component.ts line:2

```js
import TrainingUnit from "./trainingunit";
```

Comment: jeeeezzzz...thats case sensitive. That is really annoying above all that the error message is totally misleading. Thanks Teddy works now!